# Basic for loop in python 3 doesn't work

Tags: python

```
my_list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
    for i in my_list:
        print 2 * my_list[i]

  File "python", line 5
    for i in my_list:
  ^
```

IndentationError: expected an indented block

Oops, try again. The code in the body of the for loop should be indented!

Comment: _The code in the body of the for loop should be indented_. That's why it's not working. Ident it properly

Comment: Do you really mean Python 3? Because your `print` is not Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
my_list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
for i in my_list: 
    print (2 * my_list[i])
```

You have to make sure the `for` does not have an indent as above

Comment: my_list[i] is probably *not* what the user really wants.

Comment: @Shaun that is irrelevant

Comment: Irrelevant sure, but most likely wrong

Comment: @Shaun It does work. It prints 0,2,4,6,8

Comment: Yes... of course it works.  Because the list is the same as the index

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
for i in my_list:
     print(2 * i)
```

Print needs () in python 3.  And for i in my_list does NOT give the index.  It iterates over the values

Answer (score -1):

```
my_list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
for i in my_list:
        print 2 * my_list[i]
```

Comment: print requires () in python 3... and my_list[i] is probably not what the user wants -- it appears he wants to iterate over the values.  print(2*i)